# Is Nasdaq stock an ETF?

Tags: etf, stock-markets, index-fund, market-indexes, nasdaq

Newb here.

Is https://robinhood.com/stocks/NDAQ an ETF, aka if I buy this, is it a composite index (like QTEC)?

Meaning if I buy NDAQ am I really buying a composite index, or am I just investing in the company behind Nasdaq... or are they the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NDAQ](http://www.morningstar.com/stocks/XNAS/NDAQ/quote.html) is the ticker for stock in the company Nasdaq, Inc., which [derives income from managing the exchange (transaction fees, listing fees, real-time quote feeds, etc)](http://www.morningstar.com/stocks/XNAS/NDAQ/quote.html#sal-components-company-profile).  Here is their description of themselves: http://business.nasdaq.com/discover

It's not the same as investing in one of the "Nasdaq" indexes, such as Nasdaq Composite or Nasdaq-100.  Those you can't invest in directly, but almost every major provider has an ETF, mutual fund, or both, that's designed to follow one or more of those indexes.